# Alternatives to IIS for Windows to run ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis

Are there any alternatives to IIS for Windows to run ASP.NET?

CassiniEx seems pretty old?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is [UltiDev Cassini](http://www.ultidev.com/products/Cassini/) which is a "free, light-weight and  redistributable web server  that can host  ASP.NET 3.5, 3.0, 2.0 and 1.1  applications and static HTML sites". (It is based on the original Cassini web server).

Other than that, there is the development web server, which comes with Visual Studio. But as far as I know, this can only be used during development/from within Visual Studio.

p.s. [UtilDev PRO](http://www.ultidev.com/products/UWS-Cassini-Pro/Default.aspx) supports asp.net 4.0.

Comment: And now there is [UltiDev Web Server Pro UWS](http://ultidev.com/products/UWS-Cassini-Pro/) which supports ASP.NET 4, 3.x, 2.0 and 1.1.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that UWS Pro is free and donation-ware.

Comment: According to it's authors cassini is obsolete, please change the accepted answer to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 10):

You can also use the [Abyss Web Server](https://aprelium.com/abyssws/), which is [ASP.NET compatible](https://aprelium.com/abyssws/aspnet/).

Answer (score 8):

Apache 2 can do this I think. At least it can while running on Linux.

You will need a plugin for it though. [Mod_aspdotnet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mod-aspdotnet) is your friend :-)

Answer (score 6):

UltiDev has released a new version of its web server product - [UltiDev Web Server Pro](http://ultidev.com/Forums/Default.aspx?g=posts&t=633). It does support .NET Framework 4. It's a very advanced yet tiny redistributable web server suitable for debugging from within Visual Studio or hosting web applications just like IIS does.

Answer (score 5):

There are some open source projects for lightweight web servers implemented in C#.

1. There's the [C# WebServer](http://www.codeplex.com/webserver)
   project on Codeplex.
2. The [Kayak](http://code.google.com/p/kayak/) project on Google Code.

The Kayak project looks promising, but the C# WebServer project seems more robust at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Apache and mono with mod_mono.  It seems like a lot of work, but it should be get the job done.  I guess it depends on the reason you need something other than IIS whether or not it is a viable way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any VisualStudio components installed, this will give you the IIS functionality on http://localhost:8080/
Dev server version may vary, of course (10.0 in the example below).

```
mkdir c:\inetpub\wwwroot
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\DevServer\10.0"
WebDev.WebServer40 /port:8080 /path:"c:\inetpub\wwwroot" /vpath:"/"
```