# Alternate to IIS server for Asp.net MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis, nginx, model-view-controller, mono

I want to light weight web server for asp.net mvc application on windows os. I have tried nginx but it not works for asp.net mvc application for me.

Comment: Why do you want "light weight" web server? For development you can use IIS Express. For production usage, Microsoft only supports ASP.NET MVC on IIS on Windows.

Comment: thanks for reply .. but i found alternate to iis i.e http://ultidev.com/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alternatives to IIS for Windows to run ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441085/alternatives-to-iis-for-windows-to-run-asp-net)